# load raw data from page replace or delete then display to a div or table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to replace raw string/data from a page before displaying it in a div or table?

A page contains raw data and I'd like to remove all undesired strings or chars such as `\n \`  and `\t` from it. This:

```
style=\"border:none;width:auto;color:#03C\">NEW<\/td>\n    \n\t<\/tr>\n\t   <tr>\n   <td style=\"border:none;\" align=\"right\"> Number#: 33&nbsp;<\/td>\n   <td
```

should become

```
style="border:none;width:auto;color:#03C">NEW</td>    </tr>   <tr>   <td 
style="border:none;" align="right"> Number#: 33&nbsp;</td>   <td
```

and then be displayed in a div or table

I would specifically select strings such as NEW and Number# and display it numerically on a div or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Use javascript `replace` function to replace any `\n\t\r` by empty string :

**JS :**

```
replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"");
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

**Full JS :**

```
var rawData = "style=\"border:none;width:auto;color:#03C\">NEW<\/td>\n    \n\t<\/tr>\n\t   <tr>\n   <td style=\"border:none;\" align=\"right\"> Number#: 33&nbsp;<\/td>\n   <td";

rawData = rawData.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"");

$("#mydiv").text(rawData); //append result to the div
```

Hope this helps, see fiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HkJbr/19/)**.

Comment: then $("#mydiv").load(rawData); 
   }); to load into div?

Comment: Use `text` instead of load,  `$("#mydiv").text(rawData);`.

Comment: how about loading the raw data from a local webpage? var rawData ="localhost/mypage.php" ? or  $.get("localhost/mypage.php", function(data) {?